# Good text editor for Ruby on Rails programming?

Tags: text-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a good text editor for developing code on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10998/what-is-a-good-text-editor-for-developing-code-on)

I'm trying to find a text editor that I can use for doing Ruby on Rails development. I have been using TextMate on my Mac and would love to find something that even comes close to that experience. My Ubuntu laptop is a little old, and doesn't have a lot of memory, so I need something lightweight. I don't need/want a bloated IDE because the performance on my slow laptop would be terrible.

It would be nice if this text editor had:

- Syntax highlighting
- A project/file browser view to be able to open files in my project
- Keyboard shortcuts (don't need them as much)