# Is there a GUI designer for Python?

Tags: software-recommendation, python, ide

Is there a GUI IDE for programming Python just like Java has NetBeans?

I wanted one where we could drag & drop test boxes & labels just as we do with Swing components using NetBeans or Eclipse.

Or is there an add-on present in either NetBeans or Eclipse itself?

Comment: Have you looked in the Ubuntu Software Center at some of the items listed under Developer Tools > Python ?

Comment: I personally recommend trying to craft something by hand following a tutorial, because if you don't grasp how the elements you draw interact with each other, you'll have a hard time getting buttons to work and such.

Comment: Note though that, for anything non-trivial, gtk apps that don't use glade or something similar will look fairly ugly and complicated very quickly. Even using glade, you will still have plenty of chances to learn about the pygtk api.

Comment: I up voted for anything like Visual Studio for Python?

Answer (score 105):

## [Glade](https://glade.gnome.org/) [image: Install glade]

If you want a wysiwyg GUI designer, Glade is your best bet:

- first, install `glade` from the software centre
- create your GUI, save it as, say, `myapp.glade`

  [image]
- Go to the *signals* tab and set up your callback, such as `on_window1_destroy`
- In your python program, tell GTK to load the UI definitions

  ```
   import gtk


   class MyApp (object):

       def __init__(self):
           self.builder = gtk.Builder()
           self.builder.add_from_file("myapp.glade")
           self.builder.connect_signals(self)

       def run(self):
           self.builder.get_object("window1").show_all()
           gtk.main()

       def on_window1_destroy(self, *args):
           gtk.main_quit()


   MyApp().run()
  ```

After getting everything set up, you can dive straight into the [Glade tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20151230154736/http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-1.html) (as Jeremy Kerr mentioned in his answer). Start by learning about the different lay–out options and signals.

---

## [Quickly](https://web.archive.org/web/20140221133537/http://developer.ubuntu.com:80/resources/tools/quickly/) [image: Install quickly]

When you feel comfortable with glade, you can start using it via Quickly, which is a set of programs to make the common tasks in developing software very easy. It takes care of translations, storing configuration, packaging, launchpad integration including PPAs, and lots more:

```
sudo apt-get install quickly
quickly create ubuntu-application hello-world
cd hello-world/
```

Quickly now creates a huge project with everything you need already set up. A gui, the translation files, configuration via [desktopcouch](https://launchpad.net/desktopcouch), and so on.

You'll see quickly sets up a few windows (the main App, configuration, and an about dialogue) for you. To start editing your GUI:

- run `quickly design`

[image]

- To get to the app's code, run `quickly edit`
- Go to the `HelloWorldWindow.py` file
- Now start adding signal handlers and logic.

Finally, to run your application, type `quickly run`.

At this point, you can get into the PyGTK documentation in order to learn about the signals, their handlers' signatures, the different widgets' methods and so on.

- [image] [PyGTK 2.0 Reference Manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507015933/https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/)
- [image] [PyGObject Reference Manual](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506130413/https://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/)
- [Quickly Widgets (not required)](https://launchpad.net/quidgets)

---

See also, some related questions:

- [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)
- [Best Visual-Studio Like tool for Linux Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528535/best-visual-studio-like-tool-for-linux-development)
- [Creating GUI with Python in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355918/creating-gui-with-python-in-linux)
- [What is a good text editor for developing code on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10998/what-developer-text-editors-are-available-for-ubuntu)

Comment: This answer is so good it's going to be a benchmark for others :)

Comment: I found glade a terrible and buggy RAD.

Answer (score 49):

### Qt-Designer

- Qt5 is also available.
- [qt4-designer [image: Install qt4-designer]](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=qt4-designer)
- [qt3-designer [image: Install qt3-designer]](https://web.archive.org/web/20170406002047/http://packages.ubuntu.com:80/search?keywords=qt3-designer)

[PyQt](https://riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) comes with [Qt](https://web.archive.org/web/20220721190437/http://www.qt.nokia.com/)'s [Designer](https://web.archive.org/web/20161204110518/http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/designer-manual.html), which is a pretty neat graphical GUI editor, if you fancy to write your app with the Qt framework.

[image: Qt Designer screenshot]

### Qt Creator

Qt's new IDE has full blown support both for desiging widgets (as designer above) and QtQuick applicaitons, which is better for lightweight, fluid, touch-enabled applications (i.e. tablet/mobile apps)

<![QtCreator IDE][5]>

<can't find qt-project.org/uploads/image_upload/creator_30_designer_mobile_app.png>

Answer (score 23):

Are you after a full IDE (ie, code editor, runtime environment, UI layout tools), or just a utility to create the UI?

If it's a full programming environment you're after, have a look at the [Quickly toolset](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly).

If you're just looking to design interfaces, you can use the 'glade' designer to lay-out your interface using GTK widgets, then load that UI definition into any python program. There's a [GTK+ and Glade3 GUI Programming Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20151230154736/http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-1.html) (with both Python and C examples).

Answer (score 14):

### Eric IDE

Try with Eric IDE. I think it's the best IDE both for Python and Qt4.

Eric is a full-featured Python IDE written in PyQt using the QScintilla  editor widget.

Some highlights:

- Any number of editors with configurable syntax highlighting, code
  folding, auto indenting and brace highlighting.
- Integrated Project Management facility to organize your projects.  The
  project browser shows all source files, all forms and all translations
  each on its own tab. The source browser has built in class browsing
  capabilities.
- Integrated and full featured debuggers for Python and Ruby.
- Interactive shells for Python and Ruby.
- An explorer window for walking through your directory structure with
  built in class browsing capabilities for Python files.
- Variable windows that display local and global variables in the
  current scope while debugging a program.
- An integrated interface to the Python Module "unittest".
- An integrated help viewer to display HTML help files. Alternatively
  you can choose to use Qt-Assistant to view help files.
- Display of the UI in different languages.
- The capability to start Qt-Designer and Qt-Linguist from within eric5.
- The ability to compile Qt-Designer forms, to produce Qt-Linguist files
  and release them from within the IDE.

To install Eric IDE in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install eric
```

[image: Eric IDE]

Comment: Why was this downvoted?. Eric is a nice Python GUI that integrates QT development. It can design GUIs (using QT Designer), and it even compiles the .ui files to python (no need to use the command line). It's kinda a Eclipse or Visual Studio for pyQt. It's too heavy for my taste, but it is an interesting option for others.

Comment: @JavierRivera: likely because this looks like an IDE, not a GUI designer.

Answer (score 8):

### [wxFormBuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/)

It also depends which widget toolkit you want to use. I prefer [wxWidgets](http://wxwidgets.org/) with python, [wxPython](http://www.wxpython.org/).

So my preference for building the GUI's is [wxFormBuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/), it is avaialable from following PPA:

- [ppa:wxformbuilder/release [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/~wxformbuilder/+archive/release) ([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

It has the nice simple drag and drop of widgets onto a canvas, and you can quickly switch to the code tab to see what it has generated, which to my untutored eye is clean and uncluttered. As the name on the tin says it is a form builder, that's what it specializes in. So don't expect to develop a full project with it, however if you like to keep the form design separate to the analysis code then it does the job well.

Comment: The stock Ubuntu version can't generate Python code for some reason. I hope the PPA version doesn't have that problem.

Comment: yes the PPA version can generate python code.

Answer (score 3):

There is a new kid in town: [Camelot](http://www.python-camelot.com/). It is designed to build GUI's really quickly. It helps you to focus on your application, rather than on GUI code. The maintainers say

> Camelot provides components for building business applications on top of Python, **SQLAlchemy** and **Qt**.  It is inspired by the Django admin interface.  You can use Camelot to develop both simple and complex business applications at warp speed.

The framework has been presented several times in international python meetings. Its advantages are

> Developer advantages
>
> - On top of high quality and proven technology
> - Views are bound to data model without writing code
> - Customizable through the Actions framework
> - Documented from introduction tutorial to report printing
> - Warpspeed to deployable solution
>
> User advantages
>
> - Responsive and familiar GUI
> - High quality editors and controls
> - Tons of built in functions such as import, export, printing, backup and restore
> - Mapped to business processes

Check http://www.python-camelot.com/ for more info, presentations, youtube videos and more.

<sup>disclaimer: I have seen this in action and have talked with the developers. I might be biased, but I honestly believe this is great software.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

**SharpDevelop**

[image: SharpDevelop screenshot]

SharpDevelop is for developing application based on .Net Framework. It does support IronPython and has GUI designer for WinForm, Silverlight, WPF Application. While Visual Studio also has various GUI designer for IronPython, however it doesn't have GUI for WinForm.

Answer (score 1):

no one has mentioned tool that has quite a lot of use in other languages, and could be be known by starting user - Eclipse has perspective for python called PyDev.

Comment: Can Eclipse build a GUI? Even in Java?

Comment: @FarmBoy: yes it can.

Comment: Has the pydev perspective got a GUI designer?

Answer (score 1):

Check out PyForms, it is based on PyQt. 
It can be used with the Qt Designer but it is also quite easy to design GUIs directly in the Python script..

https://github.com/UmSenhorQualquer/pyforms/