# Making a GUI for python program

Tags: gui, gtk, python3

I want to make a GUI for a program written in python.It is said that Gnome tool kit is helpful for this task.But,I want to know how to install it?and the way I should use it?
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit and using unity environment.Python version is 3.2

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/56225/is-there-an-gui-designer-for-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just install [TkInter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) library from software-center or via synaptic.

(TkInter is standard GUI library for python)