# How can I run Turbo C++?

Tags: wine, c++, compiler

How can I use Windows apps like [Turbo C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_C%2B%2B) on Ubuntu? Wine says "not applicable on your PC", or something like that.

I need to specifically use Turbo C++ on Ubuntu for my coursework.

Comment: might I ask why is it so necessary to use IDE for windows, while there are plenty native ones? Because it could solve seemlessly just by using any linux ide, like codeblocks or geany

Comment: @shookees It is stated in a comment below that this is the IDE/compiler mandated for use by the OP's programming course.

Comment: @Shishir,If you found a perfect solution please tell me,I am in need too.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at these questions, there are many great tools for programming described:

---

[What developer text editors are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10998/what-is-a-good-text-editor-for-developing-code-on)

[What IDEs are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu)

---

I hope you will find there something that suits your needs! :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're making a larger program, it might be helpful to use [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/).  This will let you use some simple scripting of CMake which will let you generate a solution for your C++ project.  CMake can generate solutions for Visual Studio, Codeblocks, and other IDE systems.  It is also cross-platform which will allow you to work and develop the code on any operating system you use.

Answer (score 0):

Use command line, gcc is the best, it helps you learn programming and debugging.
Use an editor like gedit, save the file then compile using command line.

Comment: I am a XII standard student and the Turbo C++ is the software with which our course is synced. @Madhava how should I do that !? Am new to ubuntu.

Comment: write the C/C++ program and save it. Assume your file name is main.c saved on Desktop. now start terminal cd to Desktop. The type the following lines:
gcc -o myexe main.c
./myexe

Comment: As Rahul mentioned, open an editor, type in the program and save it as .c. Then open a terminal, go the dir where you saved the file and type gcc -c <file> to compile only, then do gcc <file> -o exec_name. Then run as ./<exec_name>. It's easy as it gets.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `g++` for C++ programs. It's what my university instructors asked us to use when coding in an RHEL environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an editor like [QtCreator](http://qt.nokia.com/products/developer-tools/) or [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/). Turbo C++ doesn't have a lot of non standard libraries so you should be Ok using QtCreator or NetBeans with the GCC compiler instead of Turbo C++ compiler. Sure, if you need libraries like: graphics.h or conio.h you would not find them on Linux and I don't recommend you to get used to this libraries, you will have hard time when you will get out to the real world...
And don't listen to people that tell you that you should not use IDE's if you want to be a better programmer, that's just plain stupid. IDE's don't write code for you, they just make it easier for you to refactor your code and to read it easier(and a few more features that anyway don't write code for you)...
Anyway, if you want that much to run or test your programs on Windows(in a Linux machine) and only if you have a pretty powerful computer, you can use a virtual machine like: [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/).
For example, when I have to write Oracle SQL PL/SQL Procedures I run Windows in VirtualBox with Seamless Mode activated and it works pretty well for me...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org) or [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org) instead. Much more modern and current than Turbo C++, and can run natively on Linux.

[Clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205858/clang-vs-gcc-for-linux-development-compare-and-contrast) in particular is a pleasure to use if you are studying either C or C++ since it's error messages and warnings are much easier to understand.

Install with `sudo apt-get install build-essential clang`