# What do I need to start programming?

Tags: programming, c++, kate

I am a brand new engineering student, my teacher told us that we need to program in C++, I am new to programming and to Ubuntu, I am installing the latest version of Ubuntu but I would like to know what else do I need to program in C++, I've been told to install Kate, can you please tell me what else I need? and where to find documentation related to programming and the programs I need? than you very much!

Comment: You should ask this on the coding stackexchange. Your question has no relation to Ubuntu by itself (you can code on any OS).

Comment: What you need is a platform (Ubuntu), an editor (like Kate but that is KDE. You can also use gedit. Have a look in ubuntu software center for editors ;) ) and some manuals or tutorials to start ( http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/ ). and of you go!!

Comment: A c++ compiler is a pretty good thing to have as well.

Comment: @Rinzwind: cplusplus.com has quite a few errors and some terrible examples; anyone who actually wants to learn is far better off getting themselves a good book.

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to :

- **write code**: [a text editor](https://askubuntu.com/q/10998/7567) of your choice (gedit by default or xemacs, vi, etc...) or [an IDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48299/what-ides-are-available-for-ubuntu) (i'll recommend [codeblocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) or Eclipse + eclipse-cdt, etc.)
- **manage your code**: aka use a [Version Control System](http://www.techtatva.com/2010/09/git-mercurial-and-bazaar-a-comparison/), optional at first while learning but you'll benefit from knowing git or mercurial once you'll start working on non-trivial projects.
- **compile code**: install [`build-essential`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/fr/oneiric/build-essential) (includes g++, make, C headers, etc., don't go for a manual install of the compiler) `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
- **debug it**: don't think you'll ever be able to skip this step ^^ `sudo apt-get install gdb`

Comment: LMGTFY is **not** polite.

Comment: Look, considering i took some time to politely answer the question, i could just have said "google for some c++ tutorials to learn the language once you've installed everything you needed, i won't write one because the are lot of them around the web" but instead preferred to add a lmgtfy link to point out that i don't want to pollute my answer with info easily available with a search engine. So please, consider this a humorous note because so was _my intention_. I'm aware this can be use in a rude way but so are many of the words we use ^^

Comment: There are also many people that found it funny ;) http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15650/155165

Comment: @MaximeR I found it funny, however, not everyone else does. :)

Comment: Don't want to start an edit war with you but please let the people who really find it rude free to make their point as i could also say that thinking for us/them is **not** polite ;)(sorry but always been careful with the _don't worry, we think for you_ [orwellian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orwellian) ideology)

Answer (score 5):

You need an editor (Use one you like, gedit is preinstalled for Ubuntu, I, myself, prefer [SciTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciTE)) and a c++ compiler.

The c++-compiler (g++) is found in the package g++. I would however recommend installing the package [build-essential](http://packages.ubuntu.com/de/oneiric/build-essential), it will install some more useful packages.

g++ can be invoked on the command-line like this: `g++ source.cpp -o myprogram`

Later when your programs will get more functions you will probably need some extra libraries. You can find them most easily via `apt-cache search`. Library packages have the suffix -dev or the prefix lib, e.g. zlib1g-dev for the compression library.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to install eclipse if you intend to start coding in c++. It is a good IDE to familiarize yourself with as it has support for Java and Python among others to consider for the future; also it is the best supported IDE for developing android apps.

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```