# Does Notepad++ work on ubuntu?

Tags: source-code

I have notepad++ on windows and I am about to download Ubuntu but I am wondering if there's a special version for Ubuntu or can I just use the one I have now. If it there's no version for Ubuntu, Can anybody please recommend a similar program?
By the way sorry for the tags. I need more reputation to create a new tag, that's the closest i could i get

Comment: Additional Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/10998/what-is-a-good-text-editor-for-developing-code-on

Comment: Sublime Text would be my suggestion. Hugely expensive compared to the rest of the field but it works out pretty cheap if you use it all the time. I've spent about five hours a day in ST2 for the past year. I think it has more than paid for itself in the time it has saved me over Gedit.

Comment: Ubuntu comes with Gedit.  Why not use that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Officially `notepad++` is not supported for ubuntu.
However you can install it via `wine` and run through it!

If you don't have `wine` just type in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```

Then go to `notepad++`'s website and download the latest version.
Run in in ubuntu with `wine`(right click the `.exe` and select open with `wine`).

Check this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqRyBZnwQtk), that will help you.

Alternatively, you can use [`geany`](http://www.geany.org/) which can be used either in windows or ubuntu.
It's a really cool editor, that can also be use for `LaTeX`.

Here you can see a `C++` code screenshot from geany

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a good alternative to Notepad++, you could try GEdit. Another option is Vim, this editor is much more powerful than either GEdit or Notepad++. It might have a rustic look to it and take some time to learn, but it is certainly worth it.