# Packages for web development

Tags: apache2, php, web-development

Could somebody tell me what packages do I need to download to have an Apache server on my PC and to be able to use Php, JQuery, javaScript and mysql?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

For apache2, mysql, php you can install the lamp stack by doing

```
sudo apt-get install tasksel
tasksel
```

and choose to install LAMP server. This will create a working webserver with mysql and php pre-configured. You need to create your own database and tables to be used on the webserver in mysql though so installing [MySQL Workbench](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MySqlWorkBench) might be useful too.

Javascript does not need packages since it is part of your browser.

jQuery is a javascript tool set. You [download](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MySqlWorkBench) it and put the scripts in a directory inside your webserver. Something like `/var/www/{project/}js/`. You then include the jQuery files in your html.

It might also be useful to install a code editor. I am using [Aptana](http://www.aptana.com/) myself but here is a long list: [What developer text editors are available for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10998/what-is-a-good-text-editor-for-developing-code-on)